# Python Remote debugging from Mac OS to raspberry with VSCode

Tags: raspberry-pi, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I am trying to remote debug from Visual Studio Code on Mac OS. I would like to know if anyone has managed this or if it only possible from Visual Studio for Windows, or if not, what am I doing wrong ?

When I click on the green arrow to launch the debugger on my local file, nothing happens. Seems debugger starts, I get a blue dash moving laterally below the green start debugger button and that's it.No error message on the client and no connection made on the server side (script not moving beyond a ptvsd.wait_for_attach()). i have also tried to set the remote host as localhost and do one port forwarding with no effect. Can anyone help? Thanks a lot.

I have attached my config file below

"version": "0.2.0", "configurations": [

{
    "name": "Attach (Remote Debug)",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "attach",
    "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "remoteRoot": "/home/pi/test",
    "port": 5678,
    "secret": "my_secret",
    "host": "192.1.1.11"
},
and the py script:

import random import ptvsd ptvsd.enable_attach('my_secret') ptvsd.wait_for_attach()

guesses_made = 0 name = input('Hel Thanks a lotlo! What is your name?\n') number = random.randint(1, 20) print('Well, {0}, I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.'.format(name))

while guesses_made < 6: guess = int(input('Take a guess: ')) guesses_made += 1 if guess < number: print('Your guess is too low.') if guess > number: print('Your guess is too high.') if guess == number: break

if guess == number: print('Good job, {0}! You guessed my number in {1} guesses!'.format(name, guesses_made)) else: print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was {0}'.format(number))